# preg_match to get interest rate

Tags: php, preg-match

I'm trying to validate and get an "interest rate" from user input.

I'm wanting to accept 1% -> 99%, with the ability for 0, 1 or 2 decimals. I also dont mind if they include a "%".

i.e.

- 3.2
- 3.45%
- 44%
- 4.00%

The best I could find was

```
/([0-9]{1,2})%/
```

But thats as close as I could get... any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you get user input? A separate field that asks for user input only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$regex = '~^(\d{1,2})(\.(\d{1,2}))?\%?$~';

$shouldMatch = array(
    '3.2',
    '3.45%',
    '44%',
    '4.00%'
);

foreach( $shouldMatch as $interest ) {
    var_dump( preg_match( $regex, $interest ) );
}
```

Explanation on the regex: it must start (^) with one or two digits (\d{1,2}). Then, you can have one group that starts with a . (although, in the Netherlands, a comma would be used). Then, it must be followed by one or two digits. (.(\d{1,2})). That group is optional (?). Then, there's an optional percent mark (%?) and the string should end there ($).

**EDIT**: You also might want to use a (faster?) non-regex alternative:

```
<?php

$shouldMatch = array(
    '3.2',
    '3.45%',
    '44%',
    '4.00%'
);

foreach( $shouldMatch as $interest ) {
    $interest = trim( $interest, '%' );

    var_dump( is_numeric( $interest ) && $interest < 100 );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this regex:

```
/(\d{1,2}(\.\d{1,2})?)%?/
```

Answer (score 1):

This regex should work:

```
/(?<!\d)(\d{1,2}(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)%/
```

For this data: `.56% 4.45% 99.99999% 0.112% 6% 0% 34% 3.% 99% 100% .% .0% 1.2342343%`

It produces:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => .56%
            [1] => 4.45%
            [2] => 99.99999%
            [3] => 0.112%
            [4] => 6%
            [5] => 0%
            [6] => 34%
            [7] => 3.%
            [8] => 99%
            [9] => .0%
            [10] => 1.2342343%
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => .56
            [1] => 4.45
            [2] => 99.99999
            [3] => 0.112
            [4] => 6
            [5] => 0
            [6] => 34
            [7] => 3.
            [8] => 99
            [9] => .0
            [10] => 1.2342343
        )

)
```

That is the solution for matching user input from some text. Capturing from text is a bit different, so I require the `%` to present.

**EDIT**

If you want to validate user input, with the assumption that you expect only 1 number in the field.

```
/^\s*(\d{1,2}(?:\.\d{0,2})?|\.\d{0,2})%?\s*$/
```

This will also invalidate all number with more than 2 digits after decimal point. This also allows spaces before and after the percentage number.

Answer (score 0):

```
 function isPostiveNegativeThreeDecimalNumbersOnly(value) {
      var pattern = /^[-+]?(\d{1,3})(\.(\d{1,3}))?$/;
      return pattern.test(value);
 }
```

You can validate three decimal numbers with negative value

For example

```
1.2,1.23,1.234,22.1,123.123,-1,-1.122,-222,222
```

All values are valid